# Hiding exceptions and printing decent message

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net

I have wrote a webservice in asp.net which just insert values into table via store procedure. Webservice is accessed via an android app. My service should just return TRUE (in case of insertion) or FALSE(in case of failed insertion) but it could also raise errors (exceptions) which looks weird and ordinary user cannot understand technical terms so how to hide these details and to display a proper message (or redirection). THere could be many errors e.g. Outofrange exception, NullException etc.

WebServive:

```
public GPSWebservice () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public bool insertCoordinates(string param) 
    {
        BLL bll = new BLL();
        return bll.InsertCoordinates(param);
    }

}
```

BLL

```
public bool InsertCoordinates(string param) 
    {

        String[] parts = param.Split(',');
        sqlCom.CommandText = "InsertCoordinates";
        sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        bool result ;

        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@AddedDateTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[0].ToString());
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[1].ToString();
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@RecordedDateTime", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[2].ToString());
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Latitude", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[3].ToString(); ;
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Longitude", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = parts[4].ToString(); ;
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@IsParking ", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ((parts[5].ToString().Trim()).Equals("0")) ? false : true;
        SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
        sqlCom.Parameters["@result"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return result = Convert.ToBoolean(sqlParam.Value);
        }



        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return false; 

        }

        finally 
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCoordinates]

    @AddedDateTime varchar(50),
    @IMEI varchar(50),
    @RecordedDateTime varchar(50),
    @Latitude varchar(50),
    @Longitude varchar(50),
    @IsParking bit,
    @result int output
AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
   Begin Try

    If Not exists(select IMEI from dbo.Coordinates where IMEI =@IMEI AND Latitude=@Latitude AND @Longitude=@Longitude)
    Begin
        insert into dbo.Coordinates 
        values (@AddedDateTime, @IMEI, @RecordedDateTime, @Latitude, @Longitude, @IsParking) 

        Set @result = @@ROWCOUNT

        IF(@result = 1)
         Select @result
        Else
         Set @result=0
         Select @result
    End

    Else
    Begin
         Set @result=0
         Select @result
    End
   End Try

   Begin Catch
        Set @result=0
   End Catch

END
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

You can either catch specific types of exceptions and 'translate' it to something human-readable.

```
try
{
     // do stuff
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    if (ex.Code == 15) throw new MyApplicationException("Something your users might make sense of", ex); // Code==15 is made-up
}
// Catch more specific errors where you know what happened and can give meaningful information to the user
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new MyApplicationException("General error message: Something went horribly wrong", ex);
}
```

Alternatives are to not return a boolean but a custom type:

```
public class ServiceResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public ServiceResult InsertCoordinates(string param) 
{
    // ... code

    try
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return new ServiceResult() { Success = True };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ServiceResult() { Success = False, Message = "Crash & Burn!" }; 
    }
    // ... more code
}
```

Which is better depends on your architecture and how you want to consume the result of your services.

Comment: sir i am very much tired of figuring it out, could you set the code for me ?

Comment: amazing sir, amazing but one thing i don't get it is how to display MESSAGE property to user ? on screen ? from service

Comment: Depends on your technology, if you are calling the WebMethod with AJAX there should be a success handler: `$.ajax(...).done(function(msg) { console.log(msg.Success + ": " + msg.Message); });`

Comment: i mean that how to pas it from service, and my serive is consumed by android app

Comment: Just like you would return the bool: `[WebMethod] public ServiceResult insertCoordinates(string param)`. You'll have to create a new question for the Android stuff, as I have no idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
public enum ErrorCode
{
   NoError,
   DatabaseError,
   UnknownError,
   OutofrangeError
}
[WebMethod]
public ErrorCodes insertCoordinates(string param) 
{
    ErrorCodes result = ErrorCodes.NoError;
    try
    {
        BLL bll = new BLL();
        bool dbResult = bll.InsertCoordinates(param);
        if (!dbResult) {result = ErrorCodes.DatabaseError;}
    }
    catch (OutOfRangeException ex) {result = ErrorCodes.OutofrangeError;}
    catch (Exception ex) {result = ErrorCodes.UnknownError;}
    return result;
}
```